# LINQ query where string does not contain a number

Tags: entity-framework

New to LINQ and I'm having trouble coming up with a simpler way to add a condition to exclude fields that contain numbers.

So far I've come up with:

```
db.MyDB.Where(x => !x.MyField.Contains('1') && !x.MyField.Contains('2') && !x.MyField.Contains('3') &&... etc.
```

There must be a better way to achieve this. I'm using entity framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is linq to sql, use [SqlMethods.Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
db.MyDB.Where(x => SqlMethods.Like(x.MyField, "%[0-9]%");
```

[edit] Well, it's not L2S, it's EF.  I believe EF supports [PatIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.patindex.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
db.MyDB.Where(x => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%[0-9]%", x.MyField) > 0);
```

(PATINDEX is 1-based, not 0 based)

Comment: Scary, I added something very similar at the same time you posted this answer. Wow!

Comment: @ThePower Good!  So I wasn't sweating from typing so fast for no reason.

Comment: Wow, you guys answered at the exact same second. I'm actually using Entity Framework, so I'm getting ``System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Like(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`` I should have mentioned but my lack of experience with LINQ didn't think that would be an issue.

Comment: @justiceorjustus Your lack of tags is... disappointing.  Check me edit on your question.  It helps us answer correctly :(  Lemme see if there's an equivalent for EF.

Comment: @justiceorjustus Yep, there's an equiv.  Checkem.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
db.MyDB.Where(x => !x.MyField.Any(x => Char.IsDigit(x)))
```

You could also consider using a regex with `\d`.

There are a number of solutions, I suppose it comes down to what works best with whatever `MyDB` is in this scenario. You could make it more sql friendly by playing with [SqlMethods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
db.MyDB.Where(x => !SqlMethods.Like(x.MyField, "[0-9]"))
```

Comment: Is Char.IsDigit supported by linq to sql?

Comment: I doubt that it gets converted to SQL, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I tried it and got the exception ``System.ArgumentException: DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.`` I did have to change the .Any to y => because of the same variable.